# Message not sent to server with channel.sink.add

Tags: flutter, websocket

I am using the web_socket_channel package in flutter. Everything works well except for one. After disconnecting the Internet on the phone and reconnecting, the websocket will successfully connect and receive a message from the server. But channel.sink.add('msg') does not send a message to the server.
Here is my flutter code.

```
void ws_connect() async{
    WebSocketChannel channel= IOWebSocketChannel.connect('wss://...');
    channel.stream.listen((data){
      print(data);
      if(data=='hello'){
        channel.sink.add(data);
      }
    },
      onError: (error){        
      },
      onDone: () {        
      },
    );
  }
```

After connecting the server and the client, the server sends "hello" every 5 seconds. Upon receiving the message, the client must send a "hello" to the server. When you first log into the application everything works fine, but after disconnecting the Internet and reconnecting the Internet, the application receives a message from the server, but the application does not send a message to the server. Does anyone know why this is happening? Thanks for any help.